# Update Stored procedure using Table Type

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that updates/inserts using an BizTalk application using Table Type. Depending on the em_id we are doing insert/update to the em table. below is the stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspInsertorUpdateINF]
@emp_TT AS emp_TT READONLY
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE e
 SET e.dp_id                 = t.dp_id,
     e.status                = t.status,
     e.em_id                 = t.em_id,


FROM [afm].[em] e 
INNER JOIN @emp_TT t ON e.em_id = t.em_id

INSERT INTO [afm].[em](dp_id, status, em_id)
SELECT t.dp_id, t.status, t.em_id
FROM @emp_TT t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM [afm].[em]
                WHERE em_id = t.em_id)
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END;
```

Now I want to change this stored procedure to just do an update, the em_id of the table needs to be updated irrespective of the condition `INNER JOIN @emp_TT t ON e.em_id = t.em_id`. All the record's em_id needs to set to t.em_id how can I do that.

Comment: Why not just remark out the insert part? I would think that you would always want to match on the join so that you update the correct record.

Comment: If you want to update E with the ID from T - but don't want to use a condition, it will be impossible for you to know which ID from T will be used - and surely that's not what you want.